# Load webview from cache

Tags: android, caching, webview

I need to **load the mWebview from internet when internet access is available**. And when its not available it needs to **load it from cache**. I've got something but it **doesnt load the site at all**

Please help me?

Permission ive already added: 
 - android.permission.INTERNET 
 - android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE 
 - android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService( CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null;
}


@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Layout Webview
    mWebview  = new WebView(this);
    // Broadcast
    Toast.makeText(this, "Laden van roosterwijzigingen.",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Enable JavaScript
    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
    mWebview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mWebview.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize( 5 * 1024 * 1024 ); // 5MB
    mWebview.getSettings().setAppCachePath( getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() );
    mWebview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
    mWebview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
    mWebview.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT ); // load online by default
    final Activity activity = this;
    // Make WebClient
    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { 
    // Trace Errors
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
    Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}); 
    if ( !isNetworkAvailable() ) { // loading offline
        mWebview.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
    }

    mWebview.loadUrl("http://divers.ommelandercollege.nl/webportalen/dagrooster.php");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked your code and the caching works fine (tested it with http://yahoo.com). Your problem must be in the `isNetworkAvailable()` method and thus the
`setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK)` is not called.

To test this make `isNetworkAvailable()` return always `false` temporarily and put your device in Airplane mode  after first loading the wepbage once.

Comment: That isnt possible, because it doesnt load at all. even if i have got wifi connection

Answer (score -1):

```
if ( !isNetworkAvailable() ) { // loading offline
    mWebview.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
style="color:red">}// move this bracket

mWebview.loadUrl("http://divers.ommelandercollege.nl/webportalen/dagrooster.php");
// to here  } 
}
```

Comment: Your question has severe formatting problems and is hard to read. You can edit it to use code formatting. An explanation is always helpful too! :)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.