# getJSON results is only shown when offline in webview

Tags: android, ajax, android-webview, php-5.2

I designed app to shown business data online and offline. The webview is set to

```
if (!isConnected(getApplicationContext()) ) {
        myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/businesstable.html");
...}
else{myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/businesstable.html");}
```

clearly you see that when device is offline, the webview will load the cached page.
The businesstable.html get data using getJSON:

```
var gclaData = 'http://mysitehosted.com/jsonbusiness.php';
var jqxhr = $.getJSON(gclaData,function(data){
console.log( "success" );
tabladata = '<table border="0" style="width:100%">';    
$.each(data.cols, function(j,cols ){
    tabladata += '<tr><td>Business Name:</td><td>'+ cols.nombre +'</td></tr>'; 
    tabladata += '<tr><td>Address:</td><td>'+ cols.direccion +'</td></tr>';
    tabladata += '<tr><td><hr></td><td><hr></td></tr>';
});
tabladata += '</table>';

$('#mytable').html(tabladata);
})
.always(function() {
console.log( "complete" );
$('#iscomplete').html("operation finished");
});
```

I tested businesstable.html in my computer in chrome and works fine. When I try this in Android real device, the page is ONLY shown when this is offline. I am using jquery 1.11.1. What am I doing wrong? I am very very confused.

Comment: Have you added Internet permission to your manifest?

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: Since the offline version is working, I'm guessing the only difference in the online version would be unused permissions

Comment: [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259537/load-webview-from-cache) might help too

Comment: if I rotate the device the json data now is displayed. I am not remaking the view cause I put in manifest android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" I'm still confused man

Comment: I'm reading more and more, now I think the problem is my page is waiting a GET finished message from server, cause the page isn't displayed. I must learn how set a php5 header http_response_code get finished message :-/